# advice about parallel processing with python

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I need an advice about parallel processing as I am relatively new to this field. 
I have a for loop that calls a quite complex function whose results are added to a main list. The number of iterations is not high (typically below 10), however each one would take several seconds to run. Since the solutions of each iteration are independent from each other, I am wondering if parallel computing would be the way to go to speed up the whole process. In that case, what library/function would you suggest that I use? Thanks

Comment: Is there any I/O involved in the calculations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend this [Tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#how-to-speed-up-a-cpu-bound-program) which explains concurrency with Python and how to increase the performance on CPU-Bound Tasks like the one you mention.

For example (Taking this snippet from [1](https://realpython.com/python-concurrency/#how-to-speed-up-a-cpu-bound-program)):

Suppose that the `cpu_bound` function is your expensive computation, in this snippet they use the [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) library to run the function in parallel. The multiprocessing pool will create a python process for each available core in your machine and return the calculations after each process finishes.

```py
import multiprocessing
import time


def cpu_bound(number):
    return sum(i * i for i in range(number))


def find_sums(numbers):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(cpu_bound, numbers)
    return results



if __name__ == "__main__":
    numbers = [5_000_000 + x for x in range(20)]

    start_time = time.time()
    results = find_sums(numbers)
    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Duration {duration} seconds")
```

Comment: Minor note: `time.time` is a poor for performance testing. It's biggest problem is that it doesn't account for system clock changes; if your computer happens to do an NTP sync as you're running, it could easily display the wrong elapsed time; for short-running tasks it could even display negative time. It's also not guaranteed to use a particularly fine-grained clock. The current recommendation (and default used by `timeit` module) is [`time.perf_counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) (in 3.7+, `perf_counter_ns` may provide greater precision).